# How to get the time a post request was made using Javascript in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

I'm making a  basic blog application(I'm a newcomer to web development,so I'm building thisfor learning reasons, so nothing advanced), and when someone needs to publish something they head over to a"/compose" route. And when they publish a POST request is made to the server like this,

```
app.post("/compose",function(req,res){
    const postTitle = req.body.postTitle;
    const postCategory = req.body.postCategory;
    const postBody = req.body.postBody;
    const authorName = req.body.authorName; 

    if (postCategory === "movies"){
        MoviePost.findOne({title: postTitle}, function(err, foundPost){
            if(!err){
                if (!foundPost){
                    const newPost = new MoviePost({
                        title: postTitle,
                        content: postBody,
                        category: postCategory,
                        author: authorName
                    });
                    newPost.save(function(err){
                        if(!err){
                            res.redirect("/");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    res.send("Post title already exists!Revisit the compose page to publish anything else.")
                }
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
});
```

and it works fine as of now(I also use Body-Parser. But I also need to know the time the request was made so I can include the written time in the Blog Post. How can I go about achieving it?

Comment: is it simple as `Date.now()`?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for everyone's' help.I did it like this, const addedDate = new Date();
 const addedTime = addedDate.toString();

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out , I did it like this(I also updated the post Schema.),

```
    const postCategory = req.body.postCategory;
    const postBody = req.body.postBody;
    const authorName = req.body.authorName;
    const addedDate = new Date();
    const addedTime = addedDate.toString();

    if (postCategory === "movies"){
        MoviePost.findOne({title: postTitle}, function(err, foundPost){
            if(!err){
                if (!foundPost){
                    const newPost = new MoviePost({
                        title: postTitle,
                        content: postBody,
                        category: postCategory,
                        author: authorName,
                        time : addedTime
                    });
                    newPost.save(function(err){
                        if(!err){
                            console.log(addedTime);
                            res.redirect("/");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    res.send("Post title already exists!Revisit the compose page to publish anything else.")
                }
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mongoose`, you can simply add an extra property to your schema:

```
const { Schema } = require("mongoose");

const MovieSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    category: String,
    author: String,
    date: { type: Date: default: () => new Date() }
});
```

This will automatically add the date to the new document when it is saved to the database, so you don't have to do it manually.